# How can I display a range of filtered values as a comma-delimited list in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets, one called `Core Data`, one called `Schedule`. The `Schedule` sheet needs to take information about deadlines from `Core Data` and display it concatenated in deadline-order. (Simple example with numbers and letters instead of dates and tasks given below.)

Here's what I have so far in `'Schedule'` (cell `B2` specifically in this case):

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER('Core Data'!A2:A, 'Core Data'!B2:B=A2))
```

It's saying no matches are found so I assume this is a problem with the filter component of the formula. However, I've checked the [help pages](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) and can't see a problem with the condition I've created.

The formula should:

- Get all the values in the given range (cells `A2` downward on a `'Core Data'` sheet),
- Filter them so that only those with certain values are selected. (The information from `'Core Data'` should only be selected if the date in the same row on column `B` matches the date in the cell in the `A` column on the `Schedule` sheet.)
- Join all these values together and list them as a comma-delimited list.

Example (without dates, for ease):

`Core Data` sheet:

```
A | B
----- 
a | 5
b | 7
c | 5
d | 3
```

`Schedule` sheet (or what it should look like):

```
A | B
---------
3 | d
5 | a, c
7 | b
```

What's wrong with my formula?

Comment: Are you sure, using your example, your formula works perfect for me.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately, it's not working for me. Are you able to share working example with me so I can check against mine for any stupid mistakes? Wondering if it's a type issue (numbers/dates)--will need to test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message I was getting in the cell is:

> Error: No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.

It turns out that the cell I was trying this formula on simply had no matches from the filter (no dates corresponded) but instead of returning empty it threw an error. This sounds simple but it's an annoying quirk for me that the cell didn't end up empty which made me assume the formula was at fault.

While the example in the question works you can quickly break it by adding an extra row to the `'Schedule'` table with "8" as the value in the `A` column and the formula in `B`:

```
A | B
---------
3 | d
5 | a, c
7 | b
8 | N/A
```

The "8" throws an error since it isn't found in the `'Core Data'`.

Conversely, on my original spreadsheet, When I tried the formula in a cell which did correspond to a noted deadline, it worked.

I found the solution [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/wIfvyNUnxro) is to add an `IFERROR` function to the formula to deal with this.

So a formula that works for this is:

```
=JOIN(", ", IFERROR(FILTER('Core Data'!A:A, 'Core Data'!B:B=A5)))
```

One does not use the second `IFERROR` argument as advised in Google's own helpsheet. I tried putting in an empty array at first (`{}`) but this threw a different error. It seems if you miss the argument out, the `JOIN` knows it has nothing to work with and the cell ends up with a nice blank value.